# How to design Google search like result snippets?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-search

I want to design a dynamic page for showing social links. I am able to show all the links using javascript. But I want to show links in google search result like format. I want to add Title and some text snippets with those links.

In addition to that, problem I also see is getting URL and text snippets from given url is also a pain. My application is flask based written in python. Is it possible to fetch url and text snippets from remote urls?
Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

I have created a fiddle to explain better:

Link: [JsFiddle][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/amitJS/d928uamg/20/
```

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the solution on my own. Here is how it looks now.[Search snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRw7v.png)